# When Jenkins execute another SSH on a symlinked folder, php files are changed but not reflected on the web

Tags: nginx, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, php

I created a symlinked folder like this using SSH on a Ubuntu 14.04 server named `webserver`.

```
ln -s /var/virtual/original /var/virtual/symlink
```

Inside the `/var/virtual/original`, there is a `abc.php` that has content in it.

I triggered my Jenkins which will connect remotely to the same server using SSH as well.

It will execute this command on the `webserver`.

```
mkdir /var/virtual/new-folder
cd /var/virtual/new-folder && touch abc.php
rm /var/virtual/symlink
ln -s /var/virtual/new-folder /var/virtual/symlink
```

I notice that if I open a SSH shell and am currently at `/var/virtual/symlink` and then I trigger the Jenkins, the command while executed, does actually replace the `abc.php`.

However, when I visit the website via a browser, there is no change detected.

When I am NOT at the `/var/virtual/symlink` and I trigger Jenkins, the change is properly done.

I am using nginx and php5-fpm and I did set the `disable symlinks off;` as well as `sendfile off;`

What could explain this?

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine?  If so, which software?

Comment: I am using racks pace hosting for thr web server. No VM was used.